# Is 1Gbps ethernet supports for Android or Android x86?

Tags: networking, android-x86, ethernet

I have a Mini-ITX motherboard which has Gigabit Ethernet adaptor built in. I tried android 9 and Android TV 7 but it maxed out at 100Mbps. Does it have a limitation on Android OS or is it a built-in driver compatibility issue.

Answer (score 1):

That will be a driver issue. There's no sensible reason for Android to be limiting the rate at which it can communicate.

The drivers are built into the kernel, so it's possible that a newer kernel will fix this. That depends on the kernel producer deciding to support 1Gbps communication. There isn't anything that would make that happen automatically.

Comment: Is it a kernal level thing. I have tried both4.9 and 4.19 kernals but same result.

Comment: @rzshss: See updated answer.